# How can I add methods to a class at runtime in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm building a Smalltalk API to an XML-based web service. The XML service is so regular that, rather than write the methods by hand, I figured I'd just override `#doesNotUnderstand:` to dynamically add methods via `MyApi class>>compile:`, then call all the methods once in a workspace, then remove the DNU and have my nice API.

This works great, but passing a giant string to `#compile:` just feels really wrong to me; in Python and other languages, I'd be able to attach a nicely syntax-checked lambda to a class to achieve a similar effect in a safer manner. E.g.:

```
def himaker(name):
    def hello(self, times):
        for x in xrange(times):
            print "Hi, %s!" % name
    return hello
class C(object): pass
C.bob = himaker('Bob')
C.jerry = himaker('Jerry')
a = C()
a.bob(5)
```

versus

```
SomeObject>>addHello: name
    | source methodName |
    methodName := 'sayHello', name, 'Times:'.
    source := String streamContents: [ :s |
         s nextPutAll: methodName, ' count'.
         s nextPut: Character cr.
         s nextPut: Character tab.
         s nextPutAll: 'count timesRepeat: [ Transcript show: ''Hi, ', name, '!'' ].' ]
    SomeObject class compile: source
```

Surely there must be something as clean as the Python version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the source string to more clearly reflect the method:

```
SomeObject>>addHello: name
  | methodTemplate methodSource |
  methodTemplate := 'sayHello{1}Times: count
  count timesRepeat: [ Transcript show: ''Hi, {1}!'' ].'.   
  methodSource := methodTemplate format: { name }.
  self class compile: methodSource.
```

If you want the source to be syntax-checked, you could start with a template method like this:

```
sayHelloTemplate: count
    count timesRepeat: [ Transcript show: 'Hi, NAME' ].
```

And then fill the template accordingly, like:

```
addHello2: name
    | methodTemplate methodSource |
    methodTemplate := (self class compiledMethodAt: #sayHelloTemplate:) decompileWithTemps.
    methodTemplate selector: ('sayHello', name, 'Times:') asSymbol.
    methodSource := methodTemplate sourceText copyReplaceAll: 'NAME' with: name.
    self class compile: methodSource.
```

Of course, all of this would be clearer if some methods were extracted :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have template method:

```
SomeClass>>himaker: aName
  Transcript show: 'Hi ...'
```

Then you can copy it to other class, just don't forget to set selector and class
if you don't want to confuse the system browser. Or if you don't care, that just install the copy at method dictionary.

```
| method |

method := (SomeClass>>#himaker:) copy.

method methodClass: OtherClass.
method selector: #boo: .
OtherClass methodDict at: #boo: put: method.

method := method copy.
method selector: #bar: .
method methodClass: OtherClass2.
OtherClass2 methodDict at: #bar: put: method.
```

Comment: Well, I also want to change a parameter; not simply copy. Sean suggested modifying this general idea slightly, calling `decompileWithTemps to get a string that I can perform substitutions on, but that still involves a textual replacement. It seems to me that `String>>format:` probably really is the best way to clean this up at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, compile: takes a String. If you want something more typesafe, you could build a parsetree and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use block:

```
himaker := [:name | [:n | n timesRepeat: [Transcript show: 'Hi , ', name, '!']]]
hibob = himaker value: 'bob'.
hialice = himaker value: 'alice'.
hialice value: 2
```

You can still make himaker a method

```
himaker: name
    ^[:n | n timesRepeat: [Transcript show: 'Hi, ', name, '!']]
```

Comment: If you could *bind* a block to a method, that'd be perfect, but I don't see any way to do that short of decompiling into the AST, modifying it to be a method AST, recompiling, and then attaching to the class. Not exactly trivial.

Comment: Ha I see, I think that is because in Python method and blok coincide. While in smalltalk the return semantic make block and method distinct "object". Otherwise you could have done `AClass mathodAt: #myselector put: aBlock block` (In GNU Smalltalk)

Comment: Smalltalk methods are instances of CompiledMethod in the class's method dictionary.  Thanks to duck typing, if you really wanted to put a block in this dictionary, you could subclass BlockClosure and add some required methods from CompiledMethod (e.g. #run:with:in:), and it would act just like a compiled method (see [Pharo By Example](http://pharobyexample.org/) Chapter 14.7).  This is a useful technique, but seems like overkill here.

Comment: @Sean DeNigris : I am not talking of the #run:with:in: trick rather  I am talking of leting the VM think that you have a CM in the methodDict. This is not for Pharo(block reference the CM for the bytecode) but in gnu smalltalk block are real compiled code (CompiledBlock). So in gnu smalltalk if the bytecode non-local-return it could work. Still I am not sure that the outer-context-pop-push would work.