# How do I replace a message body programmatically in Smalltalk?

Tags: metaprogramming, smalltalk

As part of some testing, I'm looking to, temporarily, replace the contents of a message with one that will return a predictable set of test values. What is the standard Smalltalk-y way to do this type of work? Is there some sample code for me to look at?

Some clarification:

- No, this is not a simple unit test. I'm testing a large, complex, system.
- Replacing the whole object at runtime is impractical. Significant accumulated state would have to be twiddled by the test, beyond replacing the method.
- Subclassing and replacing one method doesn't generalize. I'm testing dozens of similar classes and thousands of objects. Filling up the class hierarchy with tiny one method classes, one for each test-case, would really suck - and it would suck even more to have to update them if I change my test case.

Here's some pseudocode for what I'm looking to write:

```
replaceMessage: 'fibonacci' 
       onClass: 'funFunctions' 
          with: 'returnsPredictableNumbersWithoutCalculatingThem'.

self runTestSet1.

restoreMessage: 'fibonacci' 
       onClass: 'funFunctions'.

self runFollowUpSet1. "Depends on state set by Set1"

replaceMessage: 'fibonacci' 
       onClass: 'funFunctions' 
          with: 'returnsPredictableNumbersWithoutCalculatingThemPart2'.

self runFollowUpSet2. "Depends on state set by followupset1"

restoreMessage: 'fibonacci' 
       onClass: 'funFunctions'.
```

Comment: Replacing the whole object at runtime is *practical*, and standard smalltalk idiom. By one that delegates nearly everything to the one it proxies for.

Comment: @Stephan can you provide an example of this idiom at work, please? Would the replacement object take the place of the original in the inheritance hierarchy (so I could, for example, replace an ancestor for O(100000) live objects), or would I have to find, and then replace, each individual object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460991/how-can-i-add-methods-to-a-class-at-runtime-in-smalltalk might be enough, if you want changes for all instances of a class. Otherwise, you have to find and replace each individual one. 100K objects should be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace one message with another you could:

a) in corresponding method(s), change the selector, which responsible for given message send.

b) use proxies, to wrap all objects of interest and intercept given message in order to use different evaluation path than in original method.

Comment: I can imagine something like `Mock wrapping: myObj on: #mySelector do: ["some block doing what I want"]` and injecting the `Mock` where necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this is using MethodWrappers or similar. There is one thing called "Objects as Methods", which is supported in some Smalltalk dialects like Pharo and Squeak (not sure about others). The idea is that you can use any object as method. So, you can do this:

MyClass methodDict at: #foo put: MyClassAsMethod new.

And in MyClassMethod you have to implement #run: aSelector with: arguments in: aReceiver

So, when you do:  MyClass new foo. Then the VM will see that what you have there is NOT a CompiledMethod but instead another object, and then it will send to such object the message #run:with:in:

If I were you, I would download pharo from here: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/27524/Pharo-1.1.1-OneClickCogVM.zip

and would investigate the package MethodWrappers and all its classes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe **[MethodWrappers](http://www.refactory.com/Software/MethodWrappers/index.html)** - ECOOP paper [Wrappers to the Rescue](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.49.7167)

Comment: MethodWrappers look like overkill for my purposes.

Comment: @blueberryfields - Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Look in Squeak's/Pharo's version of SUnit, class TestCoverage, as a nice example of how to write and use method wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be to sub-class and override only the particular message you want to return test values.  However, you'll probably want to read the [subclass to test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SubclassToTest) and the [subclass to test anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SubclassToTestAntiPattern) entries on Ward's wiki.

To make this temporary, you would need to replace the test object with an instance of the sub-class, then change it back to the original class under test when you're done.

Comment: I would have to litter test code inside the classes that I'm trying to test - something I'd like to avoid. (for example, initialization code will now depend on whether I'm working in test mode, in which case, it will initialize to a subclass) Is there a programmatic way to replace a method on the class? I'd like to replace a method, run a test, and then place the original method back in place.

Comment: I'm not a smalltalker, so I don't know if there's a way to do that or not.  However, it doesn't seem like any more work to replace the object under test with a subclassed version of itself, run the test, then restore it to its original value.  No changes to the class under test needed.  Unless you need to call the same method multiple times in the same test with different definitions, is which case you'd still have to modify the original class to replace the method.

Comment: So you're suggesting that, once my tests have reached a partway point, I create a subclass version of by object, populate it with all of the current state for my object at that point, then run my test, and replace the original, updating it with all the new state as a result of my test?

Comment: clarified my question some based on your answer and discussion

Comment: Since subclassing doesn't scale well, perhaps you should re-work your design to include dependency injection for the things you need to override for testing.  Note that doing this also sucks if your design isn't already set up to handle it.