# Add trait to object at runtime in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, traits

For a small university project, I need to write an application in Smalltalk which simulates an award ceremony. Here artists and bands can be nominated to win an award. However, an individual artist can also be a jury member to vote for a nominee.

To enforce the restriction of artists who are not in a jury to not be able to vote, I was thinking of dynamically add a Trait to each artist object once they have been added to a jury. This then allows me to deal with method class appropriately.

My question now is, is it possible to accomplish dynamically adding Traits to an object? I already looked at [How can I add methods to a class at runtime in Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460991/how-can-i-add-methods-to-a-class-at-runtime-in-smalltalk) but is not really what I am looking for.

Regards

**UPDATE 1**
After adding the method on the class side, this works. However, when I wish to assign an artist to a jury I write something like:

```
kurt_cobain juryMemberOf: aJury.
```

then in the method `juryMemberOf` I add the (voting)artist to a list (to keep track of all the jury's he is a member of):

```
juryList add: (VotingArtist from: self)
```

When I then inspect juryList I indeed see I added VotingArtist objects to the list. However, the original Artist object in my Workspace hasn't changed into a VotingArtist. Not sure if this is possible but, later on I need to have the ability to write:

```
kurt_cobain votesFor: justin_bieber.
```

At this point in time I get a `MessageNotUnderstood` for the method `votesFor` which is normal since kurt_cobain is still an Artist object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *very* hacky. You're problem can be solved using classic inheritance (which I'm not going to detail here, since it's homework). An artist with voting rights is simply a subclass or `Artist`. When you want to give an artist voting rights, change the class, e.g. `VotingArtist from: self`, where `VotingArtist` is the subclass of `Artist`. `#from:` could be implemented as

```
VotingArtist class>>from: anArtist
    ^ self new copyFrom: anArtist
```

Comment: Okay I see. Inheritance was also one of the possibilities I thought of but my knowledge regarding Smalltalk is quite limited and did not know the possibility of copying an object to an object of sub type. Thanks!

Comment: I get a messageNotUnderstood when I execute the code you provided... VotingArtist is a child class of Artist but yet, i get this error.

Comment: `MessageNotUnderstood: VotingArtist class >> from:` .. all I did was 
`kurt_cobain := Artist new.
VotingArtist from: kurt_cobain.`

Comment: You have to implement `#from:` on the class side of `VotingArtist`. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ok thanks this works now but I have an additional question. Please have a look at UPDATE 1 in the original post above.

Comment: `#copyFrom:` simply makes a copy, so naturally you need to replace your artist with the new voting artist. In your case, using states or decorations might be a better approach. Consider the right to vote as a decoration. Then, use a default decoration wich forbids voting (can be implemented in the superclass) and when you want to enable voting, change the decoration. That way you don't have to update the references to your artist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about the problem in terms of adding behavior to an object.  Think of it in terms of how you will be using that behavior.

At some point in the code, you will need to say

```
kurt_cobain votesFor: justin_beiber    "How is this even possible?"
```

At this time, how would you know that kurt_cobain is an object capable of voting?  Would you first need to test whether this is the case?

```
kurt_cobain canVote ifTrue: [kurt_cobain votesFor: justin_beiber]
```

If you're doing this everywhere, you are effectively doing class tests all the time.  Class tests are a code smell that you're missing objects.

Instead, consider the suggestion of using a VotingArtist. Whenever you use a VotingArtist you will know that you're talking about someone who can vote.  There's no need to test the class.  The VotingArtist would reference the Artist and could also keep track of who that VotingArtist nominated or voted for.  Perhaps the Event has a collection of Artists and another collection of VotingArtists.  You'd never ask an Artist to vote and you'd never ask a VotingArtist to perform.  VotingArtists, however, may reference an Artist.

So, now the question is, should the VotingArtist respond to the same messages as Artist?  Will you ever use a VotingArtist in situations where you would expect to use an Artist?  The answer here may very well be no.  A VotingArtist votes and nominates.  An Artist performs music.  If you want to send messages relating to performing music and you're in a context where you know you have a VotingArtist, just ask the VotingArtist for its Artist and use that for the performing music behavior.  There may well be no behavior overlap at all between VotingArtist and Artist so there's not even a subclass relationship.  If neither is used interchangeably, there's no need for a hierarchical relationship between the two.

Comment: In the beginning of my application I construct a few Artist objects. At this time we do not know which ones will be member of a jury (i.e. be able to vote/nominate). Then when I say `kurt_cobain juryMemberOf: aJury` from this point on I am certain he is a VotingArtist. The sentence 'just ask the VotingArtist for its Artist and use that for the performing music behavior.' do you refer on using some sort of Delegate?

Comment: I would flip it around.  I would ask say aJury addMember: kurt_cobain.  This would create an instance of VotingArtist that contained an instance variable referencing kurt_cobain and add this VoringArtist to the Jury.